# Gstreamer how to record, take screenshot of a stream

Tags: raspberry-pi, gstreamer, gst-launch

I am streaming video from my raspberry using gstreamer and h264 decoder as below:

`raspivid -t 999999 -h 720 -w 1080 -fps 25 -hf -b 2000000 -o - | gst-launch-1.0 -v fdsrc ! h264parse !  rtph264pay config-interval=1 pt=96 ! gdppay ! tcpserversink host=192.168.2.7 port=5000`

From my desktop I am able to stream the video as below:

`gst-launch-1.0 -v tcpclientsrc host=192.168.2.7 port=5000 ! gdpdepay ! rtph264depay ! avdec_h264 ! videoconvert ! gdkpixbufoverlay location=gstreamer-logo.svg offset-x=20 offset-y=20 ! autovideosink sync=false`

I am looking for the following , any help is appreciated.Thanks.

1. Capture the screenshot of the video while streaming
2. Record the stream to a local file
3. I was able to logo overlay using gdkpixbufoverlay, want to add time also. Tried clockoverlay, but the stream got struck.

Comment: I'm joining to your post. Have you found solution maybe?

Comment: I wasnt able to do it the same way but used a rtsp server. I had put my notes here: https://gist.github.com/bot11/64026a09128b2e3de794.

Comment: Looks to be good workaround for me as well, thanks, +1